# vimp slider blocked by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I added some jquery/ajax code to my VIMP homepage in the layout.php file. It works fine but the default slideshow stopper to work. The sliding stops when I include che jquery file so the problem is  jquery itself and not its instructions. I think it's incompatible with some other js library. Does anyone know how  to solve this inconvenient?

Thanks

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. Can you provide any js console error messages or maybe just a link to your page (if it's live already)

Comment: Well, the site is not online right now and it's again on development on my local network. The problem is that I'm not getting any error in the browser console! So I don't know where to put my hands! 
I also asked to VIMP premium support but it requires a few hours before they answer.